# AVL Tree Memory issues with destructor

Tags: c++, destructor, avl-tree

I'm trying to implement AVL Tree in C++, but I'm stuck with the insertion, I have changed some things but nothing seemed to effectively solve the problem. I used Xcode's Address Sanitizer and I'm getting that error after inserting a second element into the tree:

Thread 1: Use of deallocated memory detected.
==3822==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address.....

This is the implementation of the tree so far:

**RoadTree.hpp**

```
#ifndef RoadTree_hpp
#define RoadTree_hpp

#include "Road.hpp"

class RoadTree {

private:
    struct TreeNode {
        Road *key;
        TreeNode *rightChild;
        TreeNode *leftChild;
        int height;

        TreeNode() : key(NULL), rightChild(NULL), leftChild(NULL), height(0) { }
        TreeNode(Road *r) : key(r), rightChild(NULL), leftChild(NULL), height(0) { }
    };

    TreeNode *root;
    int numberOfRoads;

    int GetHeight(TreeNode *n) const;
    void SimpleRightRotation(TreeNode *&n);
    void DoubleRightRotation(TreeNode *&n);
    void SimpleLeftRotation(TreeNode *&n);
    void DoubleLeftRotation(TreeNode *&n);
    void Insert(TreeNode *&n, Road *r);
    void ClearTree(TreeNode *&n);
    void PreOrder(TreeNode *n) const;

public:
    RoadTree();
    ~RoadTree();
    void Insert(Road *r);
    Road *FindRoad(string destination);
    void ListRoads();
    void ClearTree();
    void PreOrder();

    inline int RoadCount() {
        return numberOfRoads;
    }
};

#endif /* RoadTree_hpp */
```

**RoadTree.cpp**

```
#include "RoadTree.hpp"

RoadTree::RoadTree() : root(NULL), numberOfRoads(0) { }

RoadTree::~RoadTree() {
    ClearTree(root);
}

void RoadTree::Insert(Road *r) {
    Insert(root, r);
}

int RoadTree::GetHeight(TreeNode *n) const {
    if (n == NULL)
        return -1;
    else
        return n->height;
}

void RoadTree::SimpleRightRotation(TreeNode *&n) {
    TreeNode *tempNode = n->rightChild;
    n->rightChild = tempNode->leftChild;
    tempNode->leftChild = n;

    n->height = 1 + max(GetHeight(n->leftChild), GetHeight(n->rightChild));
    n = tempNode;
    tempNode->height = 1 + max(n->height, GetHeight(tempNode->rightChild));
}

void RoadTree::DoubleRightRotation(TreeNode *&n) {
    SimpleLeftRotation(n->rightChild);
    SimpleRightRotation(n);
}

void RoadTree::SimpleLeftRotation(TreeNode *&n) {
    TreeNode *tempNode = n->leftChild;
    n->leftChild = tempNode->rightChild;
    tempNode->rightChild = n;

    n->height = 1 + max(GetHeight(n->leftChild), GetHeight(n->rightChild));
    n = tempNode;
    tempNode->height = 1 + max(n->height, GetHeight(n->leftChild));
}

void RoadTree::DoubleLeftRotation(TreeNode *&n) {
    SimpleRightRotation(n->leftChild);
    SimpleLeftRotation(n);
}

void RoadTree::ClearTree(TreeNode *&n) {
    if (n != NULL) {
        ClearTree(n->rightChild);
        ClearTree(n->leftChild);
        delete n;
    }

    n = NULL;
}

void RoadTree::Insert(TreeNode *&n, Road *r) {
    if (n == NULL) {
        n = new TreeNode(r);
        numberOfRoads++;
    } else {
        if (r->GetDestination() < n->key->GetDestination()) {
            Insert(n->leftChild, r);
            if ((GetHeight(n->leftChild) - GetHeight(n->rightChild)) == 2) {
                if (r->GetDestination() < n->leftChild->key->GetDestination())
                    SimpleLeftRotation(n);
                else
                    DoubleLeftRotation(n);
            }
        } else if (r->GetDestination() > n->key->GetDestination()) {
            Insert(n->rightChild, r);
            if ((GetHeight(n->rightChild) - GetHeight(n->leftChild)) == 2) {
                if (r->GetDestination() > n->rightChild->key->GetDestination())
                    SimpleRightRotation(n);
                else
                    DoubleRightRotation(n);
            }
        } else if (r->GetDestination() == n->key->GetDestination())
            n->key->SetRoad(r->GetDestination(), r->GetCost(), r->GetInfo());
    }

    n->height = 1 + max(GetHeight(n->leftChild), GetHeight(n->rightChild));
}

Road *RoadTree::FindRoad(string destination) {
    TreeNode *n = root;
    while (n != NULL) {
        string current = n->key->GetDestination();
        if (destination < current)
            n = n->leftChild;
        else if (destination > current)
            n = n->rightChild;
        else if (destination == current)
            return n->key;
    }

    return NULL;
}

void RoadTree::PreOrder(TreeNode *n) const {
    if (n != NULL) {
        cout << " " << n->key->GetDestination() << " ";
        PreOrder(n->leftChild);
        PreOrder(n->rightChild);
    }
}

void RoadTree::PreOrder() {
    PreOrder(root);
}

void RoadTree::ListRoads() {

}

void RoadTree::ClearTree() {
    ClearTree(root);
}
```

And this is the implementation of Road:

**Road.hpp**

```
#ifndef Road_hpp
#define Road_hpp

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Road {

private:
    string destination;
    int cost;
    string info;

public:
    Road();
    Road(string destination, int cost, string info);

    inline string GetDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    inline int GetCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    inline string GetInfo() {
        return info;
    }
};

#endif /* Road_hpp */
```

**Road.cpp**

```
#include "Road.hpp"

Road::Road() {
    destination = "";
    cost = 0;
    info = "";
}

Road::Road(string destination, int cost, string info) {
    this->destination = destination;
    this->cost = cost;
    this->info = info;
}
```

The only way I can insert more than 1 element is leaving the destructor blank, then no error shows, so I don't know what's causing it to fail. The error is showing up at the Insertion method, in the line that compares the elements in order to advance in the tree.

**Update:** Since this is part of a bigger project, I'm almost 100% sure that the problem isn't from the tree's implementation (I put the tree and Road class in a separate project and everything worked as intended). The full project has a class called Place, it has a name and info, as well as an AVL Tree for each place (where I store the place's roads). Those places are stored in a Hash Table (that I have implemented myself).

This is the implementation of the Place class:

**Place.hpp**

```
#ifndef Place_hpp
#define Place_hpp

#include <iostream>
#include "Road.hpp"
#include "RoadTree.hpp"

using namespace std;

class Place {

private:
    string name;
    string info;
    RoadTree adjacentRoads;

public:
    Place();
    Place(string name, string info);
    void InsertRoad(Road *r);
    Road *FindRoad(string destination);
    void ListRoads();

    inline string GetName() {
        return name;
    }

    inline string GetInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    inline void SetPlace(string newName, string newInfo) {
        name = newName;
        info = newInfo;
    }

    inline void Write() {
        cout << name << endl;
        cout << "Info: " << info << endl;
    }
};
```

**Place.cpp**

```
#include "Place.hpp"

Place::Place() {
    name = "";
    info = "";
}

Place::Place(string name, string info) {
    this->name = name;
    this->info = info;
}

void Place::InsertRoad(Road *r) {
    adjacentRoads.Insert(r);
}

Road *Place::FindRoad(string destination) {
    return adjacentRoads.FindRoad(destination);
}

void Place::ListRoads() {
    adjacentRoads.ListRoads();
}
```

This is how I get a pointer from the Hash Table (if the full code is needed tell me):

```
Place *HashTable::Find(string key) {
    unsigned long hashedKey = HashFunction(key);

    list<Place>::iterator current;

    for (current = table[hashedKey].begin(); current != table[hashedKey].end(); current++) {
        Place currentPlace = *current;
        if (currentPlace.GetName() == key)
            return &*current;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

And this is an example of a main that gives me the *Thread 1: Use of deallocated memory detected.* error

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    //Declare a HashTable to store Places
    HashTable map;

    //Declare some places
    Place p1("Murcia", "10");
    Place p2("Lorca", "11");
    Place p3("Cartagena", "12");
    Place p4("Zaragoza", "13");
    Place p5("Madrid", "14");
    Place p6("Galicia", "15");

    //Insert those places into the HashTable
    map.Insert(p1);
    map.Insert(p2);
    map.Insert(p3);
    map.Insert(p4);
    map.Insert(p5);
    map.Insert(p6);

    //Declare some roads
    Road *r1 = new Road(p2.GetName(), 20, "asdgasdg");
    Road *r2 = new Road(p3.GetName(), 61, "asdgsw2");

    //Get a pointer of a place from the HashTable to insert roads in it
    Place *p1f = map.Find(p1.GetName());

    //Check if it's not null, if it's not then insert the first road, 
    //get a pointer of it and print the name        
    if (p1f != NULL) {
        p1f->InsertRoad(r1);
        Road *r1f = p1f->FindRoad(p2.GetName());
        cout << r1f->GetDestination() << endl;
    }

    //Get pointer of a place again (each time you want to insert a road
    //in a place you must get it's pointer from the HashTable
    Place *p2f = map.Find(p1.GetName());

    //Checks again and insert second road, then throws error after that
    if (p2f != NULL) {
        p2f->InsertRoad(r2);
        Road *r2f = p1f->FindRoad(p3.GetName());
        cout << r2f->GetDestination() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
```

**Update 2:** Added HashTable implementation

**HashTable.hpp**

```
#ifndef HashTable_hpp
#define HashTable_hpp

#include "Place.hpp"
#include <list>

class HashTable {

private:
    list<Place> *table;
    int numberOfEntries;
    int currentTableSize;
    float maxLoadFactor;

    unsigned int HashFunction(string key);
    bool LoadFactorExceeded();
    void ResizeTable();
    bool IsPrime(int number);
    int NextPrime(int number);

public:
    HashTable();
    ~HashTable();
    void Insert(Place p);
    Place *Find(string key);
    void EmptyTable();
    void ListPlaces();

    inline int Count() {
        return numberOfEntries;
    }
};

#endif /* HashTable_hpp */
```

**HashTable.cpp**

```
#include "HashTable.hpp"
#include <algorithm>

const int START_SIZE = 101;

HashTable::HashTable() {
    table = new list<Place>[START_SIZE];
    numberOfEntries = 0;
    maxLoadFactor = 2.0f;
    currentTableSize = START_SIZE;

    for (int i = 0; i < START_SIZE; i++) {
        table[i].clear();
    }
}

HashTable::~HashTable() {
    delete [] table;
}

unsigned int HashTable::HashFunction(string key) {
    unsigned long hashValue = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
        hashValue = 47 * hashValue + key[i];

    return (hashValue % currentTableSize);
}

bool HashTable::LoadFactorExceeded() {
    float currentLoadFactor = numberOfEntries / currentTableSize;

    if (currentLoadFactor > maxLoadFactor)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void HashTable::ResizeTable() {
    list<Place> *oldTable = table;
    int oldTableSize = currentTableSize;

    currentTableSize *= 2;
    currentTableSize = NextPrime(currentTableSize);
    table = new list<Place>[currentTableSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < currentTableSize; i++)
        table[i].clear();

    numberOfEntries = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < oldTableSize; i++) {
        list<Place>::iterator current;
        for (current = oldTable[i].begin(); current != oldTable[i].end(); current++)
            Insert(*current);
    }

    delete [] oldTable;
}

bool HashTable::IsPrime(int number) {
    if (number % 2 == 0 || number % 3 == 0)
        return false;

    int divisor = 6;
    while (divisor * divisor - 2 * divisor + 1 <= number) {
        if (number % (divisor - 1) == 0)
            return false;

        if (number % (divisor + 1) == 0)
            return false;

        divisor += 6;
    }

    return true;
}

int HashTable::NextPrime(int number) {
    while (!IsPrime(++number)) {}
    return number;
}

void HashTable::Insert(Place p) {

    unsigned long hashedKey = HashFunction(p.GetName());

    list<Place>::iterator current = table[hashedKey].begin();

    if (!table[hashedKey].empty()) {
        for (current = table[hashedKey].begin(); current != table[hashedKey].end(); current++) {
            Place &currentPlace = *current;

            if (currentPlace.GetName() == p.GetName()) {
                currentPlace.SetPlace(p.GetName(), p.GetInfo());
                break;
            } else if (current == --table[hashedKey].end()) {
                table[hashedKey].push_back(p);
                numberOfEntries++;
            }
        }
    } else {
        table[hashedKey].push_back(p);
        numberOfEntries++;
    }

    if (LoadFactorExceeded())
        ResizeTable();
}

Place *HashTable::Find(string key) {
    unsigned long hashedKey = HashFunction(key);

    list<Place>::iterator current;

    for (current = table[hashedKey].begin(); current != table[hashedKey].end(); current++) {
        Place currentPlace = *current;
        if (currentPlace.GetName() == key)
            return &*current;
    }

    return NULL;
}

void HashTable::EmptyTable() {
    for (int i = 0; i < currentTableSize; i++) {
        table[i].clear();
    }

    table = new list<Place>[START_SIZE];
    numberOfEntries = 0;
    currentTableSize = START_SIZE;
}

void HashTable::ListPlaces() {
    list<string> places;

    for (int i = 0; i < currentTableSize; i++) {
        list<Place>::iterator current;
        for (current = table[i].begin(); current != table[i].end(); current++)
            places.push_back(current->GetName());
    }

    places.sort();

    for (list<string>::iterator current = places.begin(); current != places.end(); current++)
        cout << *current << endl;

    cout << "Total: " << numberOfEntries << " lugares" << endl;
}
```

**What could be causing the problem?**

Comment: Why are you comparing strings (destinations) and not the cost of the Roads?

Comment: I don't always set a cost for each road, so I insert them by name. Anyways, I've tried sorting by cost but does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is it, but I noticed something: it looks like a linked list, and your recursive `ClearTree` function will attempt to free items repeatedly:

```
void RoadTree::ClearTree(TreeNode *&n) {
    if (n != NULL) {
        ClearTree(n->rightChild);
        ClearTree(n->leftChild);
        delete n;
    }
    n = NULL;
}
```

Assuming there are 2 elements in the list, and we call it with the first element:

```
   ClearTree( firstElement );
```

It will then first

```
        ClearTree(n->rightChild);   // 2nd element
```

which in turn will first call

```
       ClearTree(n->rightChild);    // non-existing 3rd element: NOP
```

and proceed with

```
       ClearTree(n->leftChild);     // first element again
```

Maybe if you didn't get the error, this would recurse until you get a stack overflow?

You could simply remove the call to `ClearTree(n->leftChild)` to fix it; the function will recurse across the `rightChild` until it reaches the end, then delete the nodes from last to first when it backtracks.

Perhaps it's better to just iterate over the list: (untested, hope this works)

```
TreeNode * cur = n;
while ( cur != NULL )
    TreeNode * next = n->rightChild;
    delete cur;
    cur = next;
}
n = NULL;
```

**UPDATE**

I've found the problem. Here's my debug output:

```
> g++ -O0 -g *cpp && gdb ./a.out
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/kenney/roadtree/a.out
= INITIALIZING PLACES =
--> RoadTree[0x7fffffffe1a0] CONSTRUCTOR root: 0
--> RoadTree[0x7fffffffe1c0] CONSTRUCTOR root: 0
--> RoadTree[0x7fffffffe1e0] CONSTRUCTOR root: 0
--> RoadTree[0x7fffffffe200] CONSTRUCTOR root: 0
--> RoadTree[0x7fffffffe220] CONSTRUCTOR root: 0
--> RoadTree[0x7fffffffe240] CONSTRUCTOR root: 0
= INSERTING PLACES =
<-- RoadTree[0x7fffffffe340] DESTRUCTOR! root: 0
<-- RoadTree[0x7fffffffe360] DESTRUCTOR! root: 0
<-- RoadTree[0x7fffffffe380] DESTRUCTOR! root: 0
<-- RoadTree[0x7fffffffe3a0] DESTRUCTOR! root: 0
<-- RoadTree[0x7fffffffe3c0] DESTRUCTOR! root: 0
<-- RoadTree[0x7fffffffe3e0] DESTRUCTOR! root: 0
= CREATING ROADS =
```

These are the `p1..p6` and the `map.Insert(p1..p6)`. There's already a hint that something is wrong. Next this code is run:

> ```
> cout << "= p1 =\n";
> Place *p1f = map.Find(p1.GetName());
> cout << "found " << p1f << " for " << p1.GetName() << "\n";
> ```

Producing this debug output:

```
= p1 =
<-- RoadTree[0x7fffffffe110] DESTRUCTOR! root: 0
found 0x6098f0 for Murcia
```

Then,

> ```
> if (p1f != NULL) {
>     p1f->InsertRoad(r1);
>     Road *r1f = p1f->FindRoad(p2.GetName());
>     cout << r1f->GetDestination() << endl;
> }
> ```

outputting this debug from `RoadTree::Insert`, indicating that the first if statement's 'then' is executed, assigning a new TreeNode to `n`:

```
  n null, allocating.                                         
--> TreeNode[0x609ad0] CONSTRUCTOR
  allocated TreeNode 0x609ad0 key: 0x609a60 dest: Lorca
Lorca
```

So far so good, now the same again for `p2`. First the output of `map.Find`:

```
= p2 =       
FINDING Murcia
<-- RoadTree[0x7fffffffe110] DESTRUCTOR! root: 0x609ad0
!!! RoadTree::ClearTree:: delete 0x609a60
<-- TreeNode[0x609ad0] DESTRUCTOR
found 0x6098f0 for Murcia
```

Next we continue to `p2f->InsertRoad(r2);` which is basically `Place.adjacentroads.Insert` aka `RoadTree.insert`:

```
  n not null: 0x609ad0 key: 0x609af0
```

Note the address of `n`: this is the deleted TreeNode. 
Here, the 'else' of the 'if' in `RoadTree::Insert` is taken since `n != NULL`:

> ```
>     if (r->GetDestination() < n->key->GetDestination()) {
> ```

is executed, causing:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7b9126b in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7b9126b in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00000000004046b3 in Road::GetDestination (this=0x609af0) at Road.hpp:20
#2  0x0000000000405121 in RoadTree::Insert (this=0x609900, n=@0x609900: 0x609ad0, r=0x609ab0) at RoadTree.cpp:75
#3  0x0000000000404c0d in RoadTree::Insert (this=0x609900, r=0x609ab0) at RoadTree.cpp:15
#4  0x0000000000404845 in Place::InsertRoad (this=0x6098f0, r=0x609ab0) at Place.cpp:14
#5  0x000000000040401d in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe5f8) at main.cpp:63
(gdb)
```

The fault is apparent in the `n->key->GetDestination()` which attempts to return a copy of a `string` that is already deleted, causing a segfault because some pointers are already overwritten.

The problem is in `HashTable::Find`, which does this:

```
      Place currentPlace = *current;
      if (currentPlace.GetName() == key)
          return &*current;
```

which constructs a `Place` copy on the stack that gets destroyed when the method returns. The private fields of `Place` also get destroyed, including the `string name`, which was attempted to be returned by `Road::GetDestination()`.

Replacing it with this with this solves it:

```
      if (current->GetName() == key)
          return &*current;
```

I'm not sure this is the only fix needed, but it's a step.

Comment: Sadly it didn't work, it showed the same error with the Address Sanitizer, if I deactivate it and disable breakpoints I get that error:                               malloc: *** error for object 0x1003000a0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Comment: Could you add a minimal `main()` to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I added a main, and more info about the project since it has some more things apart from the tree.

Comment: Thanks. I see you changed some method signatures, passing pointers now. Added the missing `Road::SetRoad(...)`, but still missing `HashTable::Insert`, `HashTable::table` and `HashFunction`, so if you could add that then there's enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added implementation of the HashTable

Comment: Thanks - it prints 'Lorca' and then a segfault. I'll look into it.

Comment: In the tree insertion method I tried printing both strings, the one from the parameter road, and the one from the current node's key. Address Sanitizer throws an error in the cout of the key's destination. Then, the string is not saving properly or what's happening?

Comment: I updated the answer with my findings, explaining what happens and how I found out. I hope it helps! Oh, and I have a git repo with 3 commits if you need it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97353/discussion-between-darksang-and-kenney).